# Symfony Sonata 3x upgrade error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata

I updated my symfony sonata from 2.x to 3.x and now getting this Context error:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has 
been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An exception occurred 
while executing 'SELECT t0.name AS name_1, t0.enabled AS enabled_2, 
t0.created_at AS created_at_3, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_4, t0.id AS 
id_5 FROM context t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params ["default"]: 
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input 
syntax for integer: "default"")."
```

in file `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/Helper/short-object-description.html.twig`
function `{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('edit', object, link_parameters) }}`

Any Ideas why it setting `"default"` for `t0.id` ?

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38708074/4841755. Regards.

Comment: Already checked. Actually I upgraded sonata by this post.